# How to find java classes that needs a dependency in maven pom.xml file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Maven based project, and I use IntelliJ. The pom.xml file probably contains dependencies that I don't need. How can I find which Java files (in particular the import statements) that need a specific dependency in the `pom.xml` file? Alternatively, how can I find which dependencies I don't need in the pom.xml?

I have tried to comment out a dependency from pom.xml, build the project and look what breaks. In at least one case, I saw no compile time problems, but there was a runtime problem. This method is also more effort than I want.

I have also tried to find information in the IntelliJ Project explorer, section "External Libraries". But the items listed there are not always present in the pom.xml file. Each versioned item there expands to a tree with a jar file on top, and I can ask IntelliJ about the usage of the contained items. I have found the usage of some packages contained in jar files, but the number of packages to investigate simply becomes too large.

Here is a dependency that I want to know if I need or not:

```xml
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.soundlibs/mp3spi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.soundlibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>mp3spi</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

This particular dependency results in three items in the External Libraries list (there are two sub dependencies apparently). Asking IntelliJ for usage of these libraries, I can't find any usage in my own files. But if I remove the dependency from the pom.xml file, I get runtime problems.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206824505-How-can-I-determine-if-a-Maven-dependency-is-never-used-in-a-project-

Answer (score 1):

Maven offers you the `dependency:analyze` goal which gives you the artifacts that are declared in your pom but not used by any part of your source code. Beware, though, that there may be dependencies that are only used at runtime.

Comment: I'm trying dependency:analyze, but with no success so far. I'm not sure how to enable it. The link given CrazyCoder gives xml code for a plugin, whereas the code from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8 fits in a different section of the pom file. If I go with CrazyCoder's link I can run the analyzer, but it fails for several reasons. (Not allowing comments in module-info.java. Complaining about Unsupported class file major version 55)

Comment: You just need to run the maven goal `dependency:analyze` on your project, either from IntelliJ, or from the command line (`mvn dependency:analyze`). You run it just like any other Maven command (like e.g. `clean install`).